# getNamedQuery does not retrieve data

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I used `org.hibernate.Session.getNamedQuery` to get the following query from xml file:

```
<sql-query name="filterTraineesBySection"><![CDATA[ 
   select usr.USERNAME, crs.NAME
 from TBLCOURSEROLE crsr
 inner join TBLCOURSE crs on crs.ID=:courseId and crsr.ROLEID=3
 inner join USER_ usr on crsr.USERID=usr.ID
]]>
</sql-query>
```

I used the above method as follows:

```
    public ArrayList<String[]> getTraineesBySectionId(String sectionId) {
    String[] traineeDetails = null;
    ArrayList<String[]> traineesList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Query SgTrainees = null;
    SgTrainees = this.getSession().getNamedQuery("filterTraineesBySection");
    SgTrainees.setString("courseId", sectionId);
    Iterator trainees = SgTrainees.list().iterator();

    while (trainees.hasNext()) {
        Object[] tuple = (Object[]) trainees.next();
        traineeDetails = new String[2];
        traineeDetails[0] = (String) tuple[0];
        traineeDetails[1] = (String) tuple[1];
        traineesList.add(traineeDetails);;
    }


    return traineesList;

}
```

the problem is that the above query executed successfully in the DBMS and retrieves 108 rows while in java it doesn't return anything!

Answer (score 0):

I think [I am not sure] your query is wrong. you need to space while setting parameter on line 4

**Example:**

```
crs.ID  <SPACE HERE>  =:courseId
```

complete format see below:

```
inner join TBLCOURSE crs on crs.ID =:courseId and crsr.ROLEID=3
```

**Updated:**

And also you need to `setParameter` like follwoing:

```
SgTrainees.setParameter("courseId", sectionId);
```

instead of `SgTrainees.setString("courseId", sectionId);`

Comment: I guess their is some problem in your query.Can you share the logs?

Comment: Yes please share your log as @BalajiReddy said.